# How to get file folder in Google Drive SDK early 2014?

Tags: android, google-drive-api

IN early 2014 Google has announced new Google Drive API:
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/01/google-play-services-41.html.
Now i have `DriveFile` and `DriveFolder` classes for file and folders routines.

How can i get folder in which the file is located?

Let's imagine the user have selected filename in folder tree and the app have saved file path (`DriveId` to be more detailed) and saved file content. Next app launch the app opens the file using previously saved `DriveId` and shows it's content. Now the user wants to go level up and get folder in which the file was selected (to display folder structure). How can i do it? I expected to have `DriveFile.getParentFolder()` or `DriveId.getParentDriveId()` method.